# mage.exe, MinVersion, and "The minimum version specified is not valid."

Tags: clickonce

When I run the ClickOnce mage.exe utility, creating a new deployment manifest, using both the `-MinVersion` and `-Install` options, I receive an error.

```
> mage.exe -New Deployment -Install true -Version 1.0.0.0 -MinVersion 1.0.0.0
The minimum version specified is not valid.
```

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 10):

The options `-Install` and `-MinVersion` cannot be used in the same command line. This is a shortcoming, if not a bug, in mage.exe. Consequently, you must apply those options in two separate commands. For example,

```
> mage.exe -New Deployment -Install true -Version 1.0.0.0
deploy.application successfully created

> mage.exe -Update deploy.application -MinVersion 1.0.0.0
deploy.application successfully updated
```

HT: http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2008/07/16/123828.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Manual for mage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mage-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool#new-and-update-command-options) states for -Install option that:

> If you specify the -MinVersion option, and a user has a version less
> than -MinVersion installed, it will force the application to install,
> regardless of the value that you pass to -Install.

This basically means that option -MinVersion already includes -Install. And now it appears that developer assumed that those options are mutually exclusive. However manual does not mention this. So I would consider it a bug. Especially considering that manual specifically mentions that another option -BrowserHosted can not be combined with -Install.